# Modify Profile Avatar url in DNN

Tags: themes, dotnetnuke, profile

I run DNN 9.2.2.  I have wrestled with this with two Themes, the default Xcillion and the easily available "dnnContra".  I am logged on as host, hence the userId of 1 below.

Clicking the Profile Avatar displayed in the top-bar takes you to
 http://exanoke.com/Activity-Feed/My-Profile/userId/1

We wish to modify the URL to
 http://example.com/Activity-Feed/My-Profile/ctl/Profile/userId/1/pageno/2

I cannot detect where the URL is generated.  I can't find any place to configure the URL.  Since it has a userId that depends on the user who is logged on, I presume it depends on JavaScript.  Both themes utilize bootstrap, probably bootstrap 4, so it may be in there.

Might anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

To do this the best way, you would want to duplicate the user skin object and modify it, that's pretty involved though.

To do it quickly, hackish, you could add the following javascript anywhere to your page.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    dnn_dnnUser_avatar.href += "/pageno/2"
});

</script>
```

You could add that directly to the skin itself, or you could add it into the MODULE settings (header or footer) of any module on the page. If you want it on EVERY page of your site, I recommend you put it into the skin.